# Finding $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{10^x-2^x-5^x+1}{x\tan(x)}= $?

Tags: real-analysis

How to calculate the following limit : $$\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{10^x-2^x-5^x+1}{x\tan(x)}$$
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you know what the limit of $\frac{a^x-1}{x}$ is?

Comment: @DanielFischer, Yes  : $\ln(a)$

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The trick (to get a fast answer) is to write the numerator as a product:

$$10^x - 2^x - 5^x + 1 = (2^x-1)(5^x-1).$$

Since $\lim\limits_{x\to 0} \frac{\tan x}{x} = 1$, we get the result $\ln 2\cdot \ln 5$.

Answer (score 5):

Notice that by the Taylor series we have

$$a^x=\exp(x\ln a)=_0 1+x\ln a+\frac{\ln^2 a}2x^2+o(x^2)$$
and
$$x\tan x= x^2+o(x^2)$$
so we find easily that

$$\lim_{x\to0}\frac{10^x-2^x-5^x+1}{x\tan x}=\frac{\ln^2(10)-\ln^22-\ln^25}{2}$$

Comment: Hey the two answers are the same !

Comment: Yes write $\ln^210=(\ln 2+\ln5)^2$ and develop then simplify you get $\ln 2\ln5$.

Comment: By the way, I knew that, I just thought it was cool. Upvote for both answers.

Comment: Bravo!${}{}{}{}$